# Looping api calls in redux-thunk (React redux application)

Tags: asynchronous, reactjs, promise, redux, redux-thunk

I have a JSON object similar to this in the redux store of my application:

```
tables: [
{
  "id":"TableGroup1",
  "objs":[
    {"tableName":"Table1","fetchURL":"www.mybackend.[....]/get/table1"},
    {"tableName":"Table2","fetchURL":"www.mybackend.[....]/get/table2"},
    {"tableName":"Table3","fetchURL":"www.mybackend.[....]/get/table3"}
  ]
},{
  "id":"TableGroup2",
  "objs":[
    {"tableName":"Table4","fetchURL":"www.mybackend.[....]/get/table4"},
    {"tableName":"Table5","fetchURL":"www.mybackend.[....]/get/table5"},
    {"tableName":"Table6","fetchURL":"www.mybackend.[....]/get/table6"}
  ]
 }
];
```

To load it, i use the following call (TableApi is a mock api loaded locally, beginAjaxCalls keeps track of how many Ajax calls are currently active);

```
export function loadTables(){
  return function(dispatch,getState){
    dispatch(beginAjaxCall());
    return TableApi.getAllTables().then(tables => {
        dispatch(loadTablesSuccess(tables));
    }).then(()=>{

       //Looping through the store to execute sub requests

    }).catch(error => {
        throw(error);
    });
  };
}
```

I then want to loop through my tables, call the different URLs and populate a new field called data so that an object after a call looks like this;

```
{"tableName":"Table1","fetchURL":"www.mybackend.[....]/get/table1","data":[{key:"...",value:"..."},{key:"...",value:"..."},{key:"...",value:"..."},.....]}
```

The data will be frequently updated by recalling the fetch url, and the table should then re-render in the view.

Which leads me to my questions:
 - Is this architecturally sound?
 - How would redux handle frequent changes? (because of immutability, will i get performance issues by frequently deep copying a table instance with 10,000+ data entries)

And more importantly, what code could i place to substitute the comment so that it serves its intended purpose? Ive tried;

```
let i;
for(i in getState().tables){
  let d;
  for(d in getState().tables[i].objs){
     dispatch(loadDataForTable(d,i));
  }
}
```

This code, however doesn't seem like the best implementation and I get errors.

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to make a deep copy of *all* tables.
For sake of immutability you need to copy only changed items.
For your data structure it would look like this:

```
function updateTables(tables, table) {
  return tables.map(tableGroup => {
    if(tableGroup.objs.find(obj => table.tableName === obj.tableName)) {
       // if the table is here, copy group
       retrun updateTableGroup(tableGroup, table);
    } else {
       // otherwise leave it unchanged
       return tableGroup;
    }
  })
}

function updateTableGroup(tableGroup, table) {
  return {
    ...tableGroup,
    objs: tableGroup.objs.map(obj => {
      return table.tableName === obj.tableName  ? table : obj;
    }) 
  };
}
```